# Remote form post Python and cookies headers

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests, urllib

I have a script to post a form from a distant web page.
This webpage sends a cookie, and I like to get this and insert it in the header to post the form.

How could I do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried `requests.post(URL, cookies={"cookie":"value"})`?

Comment: Thank you, is that possible to get the whole cookie value that I receive ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get `cookies` from `GET` request and use it in `POST`, you can try to use `session()` as below:

```
session = requests.session()
response = session.get(URL) # send GET to get cookies
cookies = response.cookies.get_dict() # Grab cookies
post = session.post(URL, cookies=cookies) # Send POST with grabbed cookies
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot,
When I go to the website from a web browser I have this :

```
Cookie: __qca=P0-1275531178-1484650046149; _ga=GA1.2.1669629019.1484650088; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1486719631164r0.37280650070167387; optimizelySegments=%7B%224541596561%22%3A%22ff%22%2C%224547081444%22%3A%22none%22%2C%224502945149%22%3A%22direct%22%2C%224547981473%22%3A%22false%22%7D; optimizelyBuckets=%7B%7D; IRF_1322=%7Bvisits%3A1%2Cuser%3A%7Btime%3A1486719631639%2Cref%3A%22direct%22%2Cpv%3A1%2Ccap%3A%7B%7D%2Cv%3A%7B%7D%7D%2Cvisit%3A%7Btime%3A1486719631639%2Cref%3A%22direct%22%2Cpv%3A1%2Ccap%3A%7B%7D%2Cv%3A%7B%7D%7D%2Clp%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Flastingmemoriesbylisa.zenfolio.com%2F%22%2Cdebug%3A0%2Ca%3A1486719631639%7D; zf_5y_visitor=s7fL-1Wogsx-E1mBu-WkZbl-5gcAAAAATer6DQw9WNnr; zf_10y_tz=120; zf_pat=256887569$labellevuephotography$$396676290$492530544; zf_lsc=NPUPdGc1+bbM3gpqJ/i3nH4o...0
```

but when I use my script I online have :

```
zf_5y_visitor=s7fL-1Wogsx-E1mBu-WkZbl-5gcAAAAATer6DQw9WNnr; zf_10y_tz=120;
```

Is that possible to get the other parts ? At least the one starting with "zf"

Comment: Try to specify user-agent in `headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"}` as `session.get(URL, headers=headers)`